# Russian Roulette with a novel twist

Tags: logical-deduction

The gun is loaded with a single bullet. You go first, and I always win.

How is this possible?

Comment: Winning _once_ qualifies you as "always" winning against me.

Comment: yeah i forgot that bit. 'you' is in the abstract :)

Comment: you don't say what the rules are for "winning". Maybe in your sick head, you just like it when people die and you don't care if it is even yourself :P So whoever gets shot is a "win" for you

Comment: Russian roulette is defined as the practice of loading a bullet into one chamber of a revolver, spinning the cylinder, and then pulling the trigger while pointing the gun at one's own head. If you are not using a revolver, the game is no longer called Russian roulette. It's simply forced suicide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

> The gun is not a revolver, but a pistol with a bullet in the chamber. The one pulling the trigger first is bound to lose.
>  By 'pistol' I mean any handgun where the **single** chamber is integral with the barrel.

Comment: if by 'pistol' you mean the old-fashioned type.. i was thinking >! http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Single_Barreled_Shotgun

Comment: Something like that, I updated my answer.

Comment: That would make it something other than Russian Roulette.

Comment: @RichardRoe, you are completely right and I agree. However, as confirmed by the question asker, this alteration of rules was the 'twist'

Comment: @Block Oh. Sorry I can't take away the downvote.